# How To Create Simple Log File From Script

Tags: linux

I'm trying to create a simple log file called "users.txt" that contains the username, full name, and home directory of the username entered. I also want to include the time that the script was initially running.

Any suggestions?

The script name is called catbash.sh

I have tried things such as
catbash.sh > user.txt

But I have no idea how to get specific information etc.

```
clear
LOGFILE=/home/student/gg193/FileTypes/TextFiles/ShellScripts/user.txt

read -p "What is your username?" username
read -p "May I know your name please? " name surname

echo "$(date) $username $name $surname $LOGFILE" >> $LOGFILE

TIME=$(date "+%H")

if [ $TIME -ge 0 -a $TIME -lt 12 ]
then
        echo "\nGood Morning, $surname"
elif [ $TIME -ge 12 -a $TIME -lt 18 ] 
then
        echo "\nGood afternoon $surname"
else 
        echo "\nGood evening $surname"
fi

echo "1. nonblank\n2. number\n3. ends\n4. nends\n"

while : 
do
    read INPUT_STRING
    case $INPUT_STRING in

        nonblank)
            NonEmptyLine=$(cat catbash.sh | sed '/^\s*$/d' | wc -l)
            echo "\nNumber of Non-Empty Lines are:" $NonEmptyLine
            break
            ;;
        number)
            EmptyLine=$(grep -cvP '\S' catbash.sh)
            echo "\nNumber of Empty Lines are:" $EmptyLine
            break
            ;;
        ends)
            echo "================================================================================="
            sed 's/$/$/' catbash.sh
            echo "================================================================================="
            break
            ;;
        nends)
            NonEmptyLine=$(cat catbash.sh | sed '/^\s*$/d' | wc -l)
                        echo "\nNumber of Non-Empty Lines are:" $NonEmptyLine
            EmptyLine=$(grep -cvP '\S' catbash.sh)
                        echo "\nNumber of Empty Lines are:" $EmptyLine
            echo "================================================================================="
            sed 's/$/$/' catbash.sh
            echo "================================================================================="
            break
            ;;
        *)
            echo "\nSorry, I don't understand"
            ;;
    esac
done

DURATION=$(ps -o etime= -p "$$")
echo "\nAmount of time that has passed since the script was initially executed:" $DURATION

echo "\nThanks for using catbash.sh!"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do the logging from inside the sh script. For ex, you could `echo` the info that you want on the terminal (which you are already doing) and then append `| tee -a $LOGFILE` (define LOGFILE at the top so you only have to change once if you need a different file name/location).

As further improvements you can look at defining your own logger function or even explore existing ones. For ex a simpler logger func could take 2 args - message, file name. The message itself could be composed of the user name, date/timestamp etc as you want.

With the info currently in your question, this is the best pointer I can give.

Comment: I have defined LOGFILE at the top called ```LOGFILE=/home/student/gg193/FileTypes/TextFiles/user.txt``` and underneath it,      I have echo'd    ```echo "Time: $(date)." >> $LOGFILE``` is this correct?

Comment: ```LOGFILE=/home/student/gg193/FileTypes/TextFiles/ShellScripts/user.txt```

```read -p "What is your username?" username```
```read -p "May I know your name please? " name surname```

```echo "$(date) $username $name $surname $LOGFILE" >> $LOGFILE``` Adding this has now created a "Cannot Fork on Line 29" error message, now what?

Comment: What is line 29 in your shell script? I tried it in my shell script and it worked fine and I see a new log file.

Comment: ```NonEmptyLine=$(cat catbash.sh | sed '/^\s*$/d' | wc -l)``` this is line 29. the code is correct, no idea why it isn't working

Comment: That line is fine and it works for me. If you are still getting 'cannot fork' errors it points to limits for new open files that may be very low. Is this your personal machine or a shared machine?

Comment: It's my personal machine BUT the linux is on a server, I'm connected to it using PuTTY

Comment: Yeah so your script is on a remote server. I am guessing you don't have `sudo` privileges. If you do, you could try changing some limits. Even otherwise, the issue is stemming from that line 29 which is trying to `cat` a file.  Try simply replacing that line by `NonEmptyLine=0`. If it works then it points to very low open file limits for your account.